# How to get the parameters after an oauth fetch

Tags: php, oauth

I'm trying to get some parameters passed in an OAuth fetch.

In the first script, I'm making the Oauth request this way.

```
 $ids = array( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
 $oauth = new OAuth("consumer_key","consumer_secret");
 $url = $this->getUrlApi();

 $oauth->fetch($url,array('ids' => $ids),OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
```

In the second, I'm trying to get the parametrs i've passed in the query. I'm getting an empty parameter.

```
$ids = $_REQUEST['ids'];
```

What the wrong thing in my code please. Thanks